# commit using PutSql in Apache NiFi

Tags: commit, apache-nifi

I am using PutSQL to insert/update a few records in Redshift. The first time PutSQL is executed, i can see those update/insert values in the Redshift DB.

However, the 2nd time i execute the same PutSQL processor, those values don't show up in the database. I explicitly have to click on commit(in sqlWorkbench), then only i am able to see my changes.

I have tried using commit/transaction in the commands but it doesn't work.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

copy <table> from '<s3path>'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<>;aws_secret_access_key=<>' 
CSV;

update <table> set col1=1 , col2=2 where col1=0;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Is there something that i am doing wrong?

Comment: Do the values ever show up if you wait a while, or they never show up unless you force a commit? also what JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: The copy operation is succeeding?  Are there errors in the Redshift console's Load tab?

Comment: @Bryan - i am using jdbc 41 driver. The first time i run the command, i have to wait for a while to see the records inserted. The next time i run the same command, I have to click on commit explicitly to see the updated values. The moment i commit, and i run the select statement in the workbench, i see that the values have been updated.